# fancybox with mutiple title on right side of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I need to show image title, date and link on the right side of the image.

something similar to this [example](http://www.theemiratesgroup.com/english/media-kit/media-kit.aspx)

by default fancybox allow us few option like `inside`, `outside`, `top` but not `left` or `right` side of image. and with navigation buttons `<` `>`

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside',
            position: 'top'
        }
    },
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    prevEffect: 'fade'
});
```

Is there a ways we can do it like as shown in image below [image]

Fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/JYzqR/

Comment: this might help what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/

Answer (score 3):

You can use fancybox tpl (template) option and add information on callback like afterLoad like so:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside',
            position: 'top'
        }
    },
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    prevEffect: 'fade',
    afterLoad: function() {
        var html = '<span>Date, File Type, Download</span>';
        $('.fancybox-sidebar').append(html);
    },
    tpl: {
        wrap     : '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div><div class="fancybox-sidebar"></div></div></div></div>'
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8bqynmjh/)**

Comment: I tried but text is not showing on the right side of image example http://jsfiddle.net/8bqynmjh/2/. Besides this it also adds scroll bar for small screen size.

Comment: This is only so that the divs will be inside the fancybox in a fashion that you can easily style the elements to appear as you wish, you'll have to add poper CSS for this

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hypzo/8bqynmjh/5/) I realized it was easier to do like this witout adding to much CSS to the default fancybox, however if you prefer the other layout that will work aswell

Comment: Thanks you. It still break & on smaller screen title show on top & horizontal scroll bar also shows up for small scree. I will try to work on it & see if i can fix this.

Comment: I think lightbox does have responsive support.

Comment: Yes you are right that it is responsive, however making your content responsive is up to you.