# Fancybox Text on left

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I finally created my slideshow.

Now what I need is for the text to appear on the left side of the image in fancybox.

here is the code:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside',
            position: 'left'
        }
    },
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    prevEffect: 'fade'
});
```

the 'left' and 'right' are not working. Only top and bottom...can you help me?

here is a live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/JYzqR/5/2

Comment: May be [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257444/fancybox-with-mutiple-title-on-right-side-of-image) will help you

Comment: you may reset the template used by fancybox as shown in linked answer or update/overwrite CSS rules with flex :) http://jsfiddle.net/JYzqR/1801/ http://jsfiddle.net/JYzqR/1802/

Comment: Oh great!! This could be a helpful resource. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says 'bottom' and 'top' are the only available options for the position option.
[Reference](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) - Please see the section under 'Options for thumbnail helper'